# I'm facing this AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'compile'

Tags: python

I'm facing this AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'compile'

```
def get_gan(disc, gen):
    # For the combined model we will only train the generator
    disc.trainable = False

    gan = Sequential()
    gan.add(gen)
    gan.add(disc)
    # gan_input = Input(shape=(NOISE_SIZE,))
    # x = generator(gan_input)
    # gan_out = discriminator(x)
    # gan = Model(gan_input, gan_out)
    gan.summary()
gan = get_gan(discriminator, generator)
gan.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=Adam(lr=LR_G, beta_1=BETA1))
```

please help as I can't find where is the problem :(

Answer (score 1):

You have to return `gan` from your function. Try

```
def get_gan(disc, gen):
    # For the combined model we will only train the generator
    disc.trainable = False

    gan = Sequential()
    gan.add(gen)
    gan.add(disc)
    # gan_input = Input(shape=(NOISE_SIZE,))
    # x = generator(gan_input)
    # gan_out = discriminator(x)
    # gan = Model(gan_input, gan_out)
    gan.summary()
    return gan
gan = get_gan(discriminator, generator)
gan.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=Adam(lr=LR_G, beta_1=BETA1))
```